# Xhtml removing format tags and keeping content with XSLT 2.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-2.0

I have some XHTML and I need to remove some formatting tags and keep the content using Saxon XSLT 2.0. For example

```
<p><center><i>General</i></center></p>
```

I want to convert this to

```
<p>General</p>
```

I'm using the standard XSLT identity transform and adding templates for processing the tags I want to eliminate.

I've looked online (and here) and the answers I got did not work. If I add the transform

```
<xsl:template match="h:i">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

there is no change in the output. I understand why this works the way it does. The entire node including the  tag is copied.

When I use

```
<xsl:template match="h:i">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

the text General does not appear in the output. I thought this was the right way to do it, because it only copies the contents, not the full element.

How do I just get the content of the node and not copy the element?

In addition, the content of the node could be something more complex, like a table.

```
<p><center><table>...</table></center></p>
```

In this case I just want

```
<p><table>...</table></p>
```

Note there is a question with a very similar title, but it does not address this issue. It was solved because the removed node could be easily matched in XPath. In this case there are center, italic, font, style and other elements around the text, or the text could be inside a table. It's not feasible to enumerate all the possible format element orders.

This should be a common case, but I have not been able to find a working example. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The template rule you want is

```
<xsl:template match="center|i">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This is actually the default rule if you don't have a template that matches these elements.